# The meaning of phase operator in Majorana zero mode

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-phase, anyons

In some article, such as [Phys. Rev. B **94**, 235446 (2016)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.94.235446), they define the Majorana mode operator as follow
$$
\gamma_j=\int \mathrm{d}r \ [\xi_j(r)e^{-i\theta/2}c^\dagger(r)+\xi_j^*(r)e^{i\theta/2}c(r)]
$$

where $\xi_j(r)$ is the real space wave function and $\theta$ is the phase operator satisfying $[\theta,N]=2i$, which gives rise to $[N,e^{\pm i\theta/2}]=\pm e^{\pm i\theta/2}$

However, to my best knowledge, MZM comes from diagonalizing the Hamiltonian in Nambu space, by which I could not understand where the phase operator comes from. It would be natural for me to think that $\theta$ is just some c-number, where it isn't in the article. Besides, when taking complex conjugate there will exist the commutator $[e^{i\theta/2},c]$ which I don't know how to handle.

PS:

1. The author also claims that this is somewhat charge-statistics separation of an electron: "the charge of the electron is spread out over the entire superconductor, while its Fermi statistics are retained by a localized Majorana fermion that is charge neutral.", which I don't quite understand.
2. The other part of the cited article is not relevant to this topic.

Comment: I had that same question some time ago and never found a satisfying answer. Looking forward to see anyone that has one. What I could find, though, is that $\theta$ is definitely not just a c-number. The commutation relation with N is telling us that $\theta$ is reciprocal to N in a similar way momentum is reciprocal with respect to real space. The thing I find most troubling is that the eigenvalues of N are discrete, so I'm not sure it's as simple as $\theta = -2i\partial/\partial N$

Comment: It's interesting to note, however that although N is discrete and $\theta$ is not, N is not limited, while $\theta$ is.

Comment: @Lucas Baldo  I've learnt the phase and particle number uncertainty in superconductor, but I couldn't relate it to this issue.